# Font in HTML template changes in GMAIL

Tags: html, css, fonts, gmail

I make html template and I noticed that when I open it in MS Outlook font is as in the code : 'Poppins'. But when I open it in gmail it automatically changes to Times New Roman. I found the information that it's gmail default behaviour and I should secure that it won't change ( according to article ) by adding into  that table should have font-family : 'Poppins'. But it unfortunately don't work. I have also placed all selectors to this font family prop but it didn't work either. Do You have any idea how it could be solved ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
    lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" />
        <title>Reset password email</title>
        <!--[if mso]>
            <noscript>
                <xml>
                    <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
                        <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
                    </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
                </xml>
            </noscript>
        <![endif]-->
        <style>
            table {
                font-family: 'Poppins';
            }
            tr,
            td {
                border: 0px;
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
    </head>
    <body
        style="
            background: #ffffff;
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            padding-top: 0;
            padding-bottom: 0;
            font-family: 'Poppins';
        "
    >
        <table
            align="left"
            cellpadding="0"
            cellspacing="0"
            style="
                border: 0;
                background: #ffffff;
                width: 450px !important;
                height: 436px;
                font-family: 'Poppins';
            "
        >
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="
                            padding: 64px 0 0 53px;
                            font-weight: 500;
                            font-size: 12px !important;
                            line-height: 18px;
                            height: 18px;
                            width: 123px;
                            font-family: 'Poppins';
                        "
                    >
                        Zapomniałeś hasła ?
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="
                            padding: 14px 0 0 53px;
                            font-weight: 400;
                            font-size: 12px !important;
                            line-height: 18px;
                            height: 18px;
                            width: 313px;
                        "
                    >
                        Aby zresetować hasło, proszę kliknąć w poniższy link:
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="
                            border-radius: 3px;
                            background-color: #ffffff;
                            display: table-cell;
                            text-align: left;
                            vertical-align: middle;
                        "
                    >
                        <a
                            href="#"
                            style="
                                text-decoration: none;
                                font-weight: 500;
                                font-size: 12px;
                                color: #ffffff;
                                line-height: 30px;
                                background-color: #232835;
                                margin-left: 51px;
                                margin-top: 7px;
                                padding: 6px 36px 6px 36px;
                                border-radius: 3px;
                                letter-spacing: -2%;
                            "
                            >RESETUJ HASŁO</a
                        >
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="
                            padding: 13px 0 0 53px;
                            font-weight: 400;
                            font-size: 12px !important;
                            line-height: 18px;
                            height: 18px;
                            width: 316px;
                        "
                    >
                        W razie problemów skontaktuj się z administratorem
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="
                            padding: 9px 0 0 53px;
                            font-weight: 500;
                            font-size: 12px !important;
                            line-height: 18px;
                            height: 18px;
                            width: 140px;
                        "
                    >
                        Imię Nazwisko
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="
                            padding: 0 0 0 53px;
                            font-weight: 500;
                            font-size: 12px !important;
                            line-height: 18px;
                            width: 140px;
                        "
                    >
                        500 500 500
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="
                            padding: 0 0 0 53px;
                            font-weight: 500;
                            font-size: 12px !important;
                            line-height: 18px;
                            width: 140px;
                        "
                    >
                        <a style="text-decoration: none">admin@nevomo.com</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="
                            padding: 17px 0 0 53px;
                            font-weight: 400;
                            font-size: 12px !important;
                            line-height: 18px;
                            height: 18px;
                            width: 84px;
                        "
                    >
                        Pozdrawiamy,
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img
                            src="https://i.ibb.co/YhtGLnf/nevomo-logo-orange.png"
                            alt="nevomo-logo-orange"
                            border="0"
                            style="
                                width: 112.17px;
                                height: 15.74px;
                                padding: 12.13px 0 0 56.41px;
                                color: #eb5d1c;
                            "
                            alt="logo"
                        />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="
                            padding: 7.6px 0 0px 53px;
                            font-weight: 400;
                            font-size: 11px !important;
                            line-height: 16.5px;
                            width: 206px;
                        "
                    >
                        ul.Mińska 63A lok.245
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="
                            padding: 0 0 0px 53px;
                            font-weight: 400;
                            font-size: 11px !important;
                            line-height: 16.5px;
                            width: 206px;
                        "
                    >
                        03-828 Warszawa
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="
                            padding: 0 0 64px 53px;
                            font-weight: 400;
                            font-size: 11px !important;
                            line-height: 16.5px;
                            width: 206px;
                        "
                    >
                        www | facebook | instagram | linkedin
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set your font in the css using the tag `@font-face { font-family: "Poppins ";  src: url("../fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf"), url("../fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf"), url("../fonts/Poppins-Italic.ttf"); }`   but substitute the url for a cdn serving Poppins font face  or leave it this way if you want self host your font. Remember that if you have different file types, like woff, woff2 or otf then you have to cover all with the above pattern stating a `@font-face` for each of them.